# php mysql_query / modification

Tags: php, mysql

I have this query

```
$result = Db::getInstance(_PS_USE_SQL_SLAVE_)->ExecuteS('
SELECT p.`id_product`, pl.`description`set, pl.`information`
FROM....
```

i have also this variable :

```
$myvar=array('information2','information3')
```

i want to rewrite my query like this (add values from $myvar to the SELECT) :

```
$result = Db::getInstance(_PS_USE_SQL_SLAVE_)->ExecuteS('
    SELECT p.`id_product`, pl.`description`set, pl.`information`,pl.`information2`,pl.`information3`
    FROM....
```

How can i do this ?
 And it is possible to write a function for changing the query without write into the original query (=$result) ?

Answer (score 0):

You can concatenate the tables using `implode()`.

```
$tables = implode(',',$myvar);
$result = Db::getInstance(_PS_USE_SQL_SLAVE_)->ExecuteS("
SELECT p.`id_product`, pl.`description`set, pl.`information`,$tables
FROM x");
```

This will produce

```
SELECT p.`id_product`, pl.`description`set,
    pl.`information`,information2,information3 FROM x
```

Comment: thank you for your answer it helps me. Can i do the same thing without write in $result. Ex : $result=newresult($result);

Comment: Yes, just create a new variable insetad. `$newresult = SELECT p.id_product, pl.description set, pl.information,$tables
FROM x"`.